# Public S3 bucket access using s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/folder is possible but not using s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bucket/folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to figure out why I can't access my public bucket's resources located in `us-east-1` region using the following URL:

```
https://s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/demo.terraform.bucket/VideoImages/public.png
```

I get that error when I try to execute the above URL in the browser:

```
s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com’s server IP address could not be found.
```

However, if I use the bellow URL it works and I get the resource:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/demo.terraform.bucket/VideoImages/public.png
```

I have another public bucket which was created by someone else in my team in a different region `us-west-2` and I can access it using the `https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/<bucketname>/VideoImages/public.png` format.

I am trying to figure out what is going on with the access of my bucket `demo.terraform.bucket`. Why I can't access images using that syntacs `https://s3-<region>.amazonaws.com/<bucket name>/VideoImages/public.png`?

Bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicReadVideoImages",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::demo.terraform.bucket/VideoImages/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicReadMarketing",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::demo.terraform.bucket/MarketingResources/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I have `Block all public access` set to `Off`

Comment: `s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com` doesn't exist. `s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` is the correct one. But prefer `s3.dualstack.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` as that also supports IPv6. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Thank you @tambre! That worked! I would gladly accept that as an answer. I was expecting that all of the regions would all be available

Comment: I guess this could be useful to others, turned into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com` returns `NXDOMAIN` for A/AAAA queries, i.e. it doesn't exist. Domains of the format `s3-<region>.amazonaws.com` are legacy and exist only for select regions with often non-standard names. You should no longer use them.

The modern format for S3 domains is [`s3.dualstack.<region>.amazonaws.com/<bucket>`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/dual-stack-endpoints.html). Stick to that and don't forget the `dualstack` bit for IPv6 support.